# convert row into column based on particular key

Tags: text-processing

I have file like Below. But header are in different line the header Values are printed in down to the hear. I want all the header in single row & value to the Particular header to be print to below to the respective header

#### INPUT

```
name1    name2           name3            name4
XXXX     IN SERVICE      22905            dhr

Name5
123445678
12345687


Nam6             Name7              Name8   Name9 name10
firstin_firstout godwith             1234   17    david

Name11                                   Name12
dhame                                    Dame2
rame                                     Ragha
```

#### OUTPUT

```
name1   name2   name3   name4   Name5_1 Name5_2 Nam6    Name7   Name8   Name9   name10  Name11_1    Name11_2    Name12_1    Name12_2
XXXX    IN SERVICE  22905   dhr 123445678   12345687    firstin_firstout    godwith 1234    17  david   dhame   rame    Dame2   Ragha
```

Comment: A little bit of formatting might help understanding the question better.

Comment: Please edit this Q, it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following by some `script.name`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

FNR == 1 {
split ($0,N," ")
r=""
next
}
{
if (FNR>2) r="_" FNR-1
for (i in N) V[N[i] r]=$i
}
FNR == 3 {
for (i in N) {
  V[N[i]"_"1]=V[N[i]]
  delete V[N[i]]
  }
}
END {
for (n in V) printf("%s ", n)
print ""
for (n in V) printf("%s ", V[n])
print ""
}
```

And operate as follow:

```
awk -f sript.name input_files | column -t
```

where the `input_file` have 1st row with headers and other with data.